# Different color for Cells in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have datagrid in which  some cells (not entire columns) are editable and others are not(all is predefined).what we want to achieve is that to differentiate editable and uneditable cells applying differnet colors.
How to achive this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use an itemRenderer and set style colors inside the itemRenderer.  Depending on your complexity you may consider conditionally setting the style of the itemRenderer based on the data.